# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "STDIN" in C:\xampp\htdocs\imagebob\google-drive.php:41

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, stdin

when I try to want access the token the verification code is not working and they give me error undefined constant "STDIN" im new here in google API so please help me what's I do? Thanks

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
    if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    } else {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

        // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

        // Check to see if there was an error.
        if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
            throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
        }
    }
    // Save the token to a file.
    if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
        mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}
```

Comment: `STDIN` is only available when running scripts from the CLI, not a webserver. How are you running this script?

Comment: how can I fix this error its my project can you help me in this ?

Comment: If you're running the script from a web page, you get parameters using `$_POST` or `$_GET` depending on how the form was submitted.

Comment: Any tutorial on processing forms in PHP will explain this.

Comment: sir when i use $_POST or $_GET then they give me this type of error

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Array callback must have exactly two elements in C:\xampp\htdocs\imagebob\google-drive.php:41 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\imagebob\google-drive.php(62): getClient() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\imagebob\google-drive.php on line 41"

Comment: Without seeing the code I have no way of knowing what that refers to.

Comment: @barmar in this link the complete code is available with complete classes can you fix my this error 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BDjyxK5uaGoEogLwq5TJ20gAu6oPAr29/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not going to download the full code. Post a [mcve] here.

Comment: sir i just replace the $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN)); into $authCode = $_POST(fgets(STDIN)); 
then they show me error this type  -->
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Array callback must have exactly two elements in C:\xampp\htdocs\imagebob\google-drive.php:41 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\imagebob\google-drive.php(62): getClient() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\imagebob\google-drive.php on line 41

Comment: `$_POST` is not a function, it's an array. And you can't use `fgets(STDIN)` since there's no `STDIN`.\

Comment: It should be `$authCode = $_POST['inputname']` where `inputname` corresponds to the `name` attribute of the input field in the form.

Comment: the error is same like above

Comment: sir can you give me any tutorial on processing forms in PHP will explain this

Comment: Sorry, I don't know tutorials very well. But wherever you learned PHP, I would expect it to have a section on this, as it's one of the most common uses.

Comment: ok thanks a lot sir

Comment: Can you post the whole code you are using? @ShujaatKhattak

Comment: @ale13 in this link there is my complete code --> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BDjyxK5uaGoEogLwq5TJ20gAu6oPAr29

Comment: Please edit the question and include the code here @ShujaatKhattak

Comment: @ale13 i upload again my question and include my code the link is there 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66367003/upload-image-in-google-drive-using-google-drive-api-using-the-php-script-and-run

Answer (score 0):

[The example code on the quickstart tells you use the `php` command](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/php#step_4_run_the_sample). This means that you are executing it on a console/terminal where you have `STDIN`.

If you are trying to do a web server application, you don't have it and thus the code is different. You can find the most common setups on the library's GitHub repository ([see examples](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#examples)). Take a look to them, understand their differences, and choose the one that's best for you.